# The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object nodejs google cloud storage object uploading

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a image to google cloud storage bucket using nodejs. I followed the documentation but when I am trying to upload the image I am getting the error "The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object". I m passing file path as string but still I am getting error. This is my code

```
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const randomString = require('randomstring');
const path = require('path');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const configFile = require('../configs/memesdev.json');

exports.upload = (req, res) => {
  const storageObject = new Storage({ keyFilename: configFile });
  uploadFile(storageObject);
}
async function uploadFile(storageObject) {
  await storageObject.bucket("images_memespool").upload("D:\\sotari\\eight.jpg", {});
  console.log('file uploaded');
}
```

Can somebody help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error for the authentication, you must pass a string to `keyFilename`.

```
exports.upload = (req, res) => {
  const storageObject = new Storage({ 
     keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'configs', 'memesdev.json')
  });
  uploadFile(storageObject);
}
```